# Mostrar/esconder cada elemento dentro de um classe com toggle (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

Tenho uma classe `.menu-departamento` e dentro dele tenho um `h3` e um `ul li`,no qual estou colocando um efeito `toogle`.

No código abaixo quando clico em um `h3` exibe todos os `ul` e o desejado é que exibisse somente a `ul` que esta logo abaixo `h3` clicado.

**Segue o exemplo abaixo:**

```
<div class="menu-departamento">
    <h3>
        cartuchos e toners  
    </h3>
    <ul>
        <li>01</li>
        <li>02</li>
        <li>03</li>
        <li>04</li>
        <li>05</li>
    </ul>

    <h3>impressoras</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>01</li>
        <li>02</li>
        <li>03</li>
        <li>04</li>
        <li>05</li>
    </ul>

    <h3>Cadernos</h3>

    <ul>
        <li>01</li>
        <li>02</li>
        <li>03</li>
        <li>04</li>
        <li>05</li>
    </ul>

    <h3>acessórios</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>01</li>
        <li>02</li>
        <li>03</li>
        <li>04</li>
        <li>05</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menu-departamento > ul > li').hide();

    $('.menu-departamento h3').click(function() {
        $('.menu-departamento > ul > li').toggle('slow, 1000');
    });

});
</script>
```

**Referência de exemplo no jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/scofieldm1/Lcbdpcju/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) para isso, que seleciona o próximo elemento.

No seu exemplo modifiquei a linha `$('.menu-departamento > ul > li').hide();` para esconder toda `ul`. Então o `next()` seleciona sempre a próxima `ul`, já que no seu código sempre há uma `ul` após uma `h3`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu-departamento > ul').hide();
  
  $('.menu-departamento h3').click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle('slow, 1000');
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-departamento">
  <h3>cartuchos e toners</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>01</li>
    <li>02</li>
    <li>03</li>
    <li>04</li>
    <li>05</li>
  </ul>
  <h3>impressoras</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>01</li>
    <li>02</li>
    <li>03</li>
    <li>04</li>
    <li>05</li>
  </ul>
  <h3>Cadernos</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>01</li>
    <li>02</li>
    <li>03</li>
    <li>04</li>
    <li>05</li>
  </ul>
  <h3>acessórios</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>01</li>
    <li>02</li>
    <li>03</li>
    <li>04</li>
    <li>05</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado, pela resposta, marquei sua pergunta como certa era basicamente o que precisava.

Answer (score 3):

Utilize um container entre cada listagem. Veja como ficou no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1qj2phc9/1/).