# Como posso alterar com evento click o menu de um item?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou trabalhando [**neste site**](http://stanley.axitech.com.br/) e gostaria que pudessem me ajudar a aparecer somente o sub-menu do item que foi clicado.

Explicando um pouco, eu coloquei a imagem dentro da `<li>` que contém a classe `sub-menu` e atribui a ela através do ***jquery*** um evento ***click*** que ao ser clicado, vai fazer um toggle abrindo e fechando o sub-menu. O que eu gostaria era conseguir abrir e fechar somente o menu cujo evento click foi acionado.

Eis os códigos:

HTML

```
<li id="menu-item-31" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-31"><a href="http://stanley.axitech.com.br/loja-virtual" class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered">Loja virtual</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-32" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-32"><a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered">Item 1</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-33" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-33"><a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered">Item 2</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-34" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-34"><a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered">Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <img class="arrow_nav" src="http://stanley.axitech.com.br/wp-content/themes/ead/images/arrowdown.png">
</li>
```

JS

```
    $(function(){

        // Coloquei o arrow para descer os menus que tem sub-itens
        $("#topo_navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children")
        .append("<img class='arrow_nav' src='<?=MINHASIMAGENS?>arrowdown.png'>");

        // Vou mandar com toggle aparecer/desaparecer os sub-menus
        $("img.arrow_nav").on('click', function(){
            // aqui preciso saber como no evento click com toggle ...
            // eu vou abrir só o sub-menu do menu clicado     <------
            $(".sub-menu").slideToggle();
        });

    });
```

Comment: Tenho impressão que a solução ja foi publicada em [Mostrar/esconder cada elemento dentro de um classe com toggle (jquery)](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47420/mostrar-esconder-cada-elemento-dentro-de-um-classe-com-toggle-jquery)

Comment: Acho que não deveria ser `fechada` porque está bem elaborada, bem curta e sobretudo tem a solução ao exemplo que funciona perfeitamente e pode ser entendida por todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como a seta está dentro do mesmo elemento do submenu, você pode restringir a busca ao `parent` da própria seta usando `find`. Desse modo o `slideToggle` será executado somente sobre os elementos de classe `.sub-menu` *dentro* da `li` acima na hierarquia (*parent* de `.arrow_nav`).

```
$("img.arrow_nav").on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".sub-menu").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua solução, Funcionou perfeitamente.