# Organizar conteúdos e fazer "paginação"

Tags: jquery

Eu gostaria de montar um sisteminha que fizesse a paginação automaticamente apenas com o **jQuery/JavaScript** com os rows que recebo.

O Servidor pode me retornar 1 row como pode me retornar 1 milhão, e o jQuery precisa organizar esses rows ocultando todos os rows menos os últimos 2. Por exemplo ele me retorna esses 5 rows

```
<div class="MSGR">Bom dia</div> --> NAO MOSTRAR
<div class="MSGR">Bom dia</div> --> NAO MOSTRAR
<div class="MSGR">Bom dia</div> --> NAO MOSTRAR
(ainda tem 3 opçoes SR.USUARIO)
<div class="MSGR">Bom dia</div> --> MOSTRAR
<div class="MSGR">Bom dia</div> --> MOSTRAR
```

Ele vai mostrar os últimos 2 rows e o resto vai simplesmente esconder.

Acima dos rows mostrados deve existir um botao para mostrar MAIS rows.. um "load more" que mostra de dois em dois sempre mostrando quantos rows ainda faltam para ser exibido... Esse botao de load more deve existir enquanto existir rows, quando todos forem exibidos ela nao tem mais função e deve ser ocultada.. Tipo o Messenger do facebook que voce puxa as mensagens de cima para baixo e é exibido de X em X mensagens até acabar.

Comment: Como seria apenas de 2 em 2?

Comment: @MaiconCarraro mostrou duas divs mas ainda restam 5 ele só vai mostrar duas dessas cinco é assim vai..

Comment: possível duplicata de [Mostrar/esconder cada elemento dentro de um classe com toggle (jquery)](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47420/mostrar-esconder-cada-elemento-dentro-de-um-classe-com-toggle-jquery)

Comment: @MaiconCarraro não tem muito nexo, tem a ver mas nao é, é uma paginação e nao um "menu"

Comment: mas a base é a mesma, não?

Comment: @MaiconCarraro eu creio que nao pois é necessário organizar os rows recebidos e trabalhar com eles e nao trabalhar com pontos fixos.. Veja a edição.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui fica uma sugestão sem jQuery. Se quiseres podes adaptar mas não fica melhor só por ser jQuery.

Usa CSS transitions para mostrar o contudo e uma variável qua decreesce o indice do ultimo numero mostrado cada vez que chama mais linhas.

Estou a usar elementos básicos do JavaScript e removendo a classe `hidden` com o [`.classList.remove('nomedaclasse');`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

```js
var divs = [];

// pedaço para montar conteudo
for (var i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = 'Linha ' + i;
    div.classList.add('MSGR', 'hidden');
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    divs.push(div);
}

// função que retira a classe hidden
function mostrarDesde(elementos, indice, qtd) {
    if (!qtd) qtd = 2; // no caso de um dia queres mudar quantas mostra cada vez
    for (var i = indice; i < indice + qtd; i++) {
        if (elementos[i]) elementos[i].classList.remove('hidden');
    }
}

var indiceVisivel = divs.length - 2;
mostrarDesde(divs, indiceVisivel);

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
    mostrarDesde(divs, indiceVisivel = indiceVisivel - 2);
    if (indiceVisivel < 0) this.classList.add('hidden'); // para esconder o input no fim
});
```

```css
.MSGR {
    height: 20px;
    transition: all .5s;
}
.hidden {
    height:0;
    opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Mostrar mais</button>
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hqsa742c/1